# Prove that union distributes over Cartesian product

Tags: elementary-set-theory

How can we prove/disprove:

> A ∪ (B × C) = (A ∪ B) × (A ∪ C)

I know that the Cartesian product is distributive over union and I saw [how this can be proved](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/960307/proving-the-cartesian-product-of-the-union-of-two-sets-a-b-and-the-set-c-is-equa). But I can't find anything about the above property of union.

I've tried to use some variables to solve the problem and reached the conclusion that this property is not true. For example, if x∈A, y∈B, and z∈C, we should have

{x,(y,z)} ≠ {x,y} × {x,z}
{x,(y,z)} ≠ {(x,x),(x,z),(y,x),(y,z)}

But I'm not sure if that's how a formal proof would look like.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $B = C = \emptyset$, then
$$A \cup (B \times C) = A \cup \emptyset = A \neq A \times A = (A \cup \emptyset) \times (A \cup \emptyset) = (A \cup B) \times (A \cup C).$$